# Regex help for a list of domains

Tags: php, regex, dns

Can someone help me with php regex that would scan a list of domains and remove any domains  that have numbers, dashes, and over 15 characters long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over them and test with preg_match. As for regex, \d matches digits, and .{16,} will match strings that are 16 characters or longer. - will match the -, lol. You can use | as the OR operator.

Put it all together and you get:

```
preg_match('/\d|-|.{16,}/', $testString);
```

Comment: Using @morphotomy's regex:`foreach ($domainsArray as $domain) {
    if (!preg_match('/\d|-|.{16,}/', $domain)) {
        $cleanDomainsArray[] = $domain;
    }
}`